# I can't add input in internal terminal in KDevelop

Tags: ubuntu, input, terminal, kde-plasma, kdevelop

I'm new to KDevelop,

how do you type input in the internal terminal in KDevelop?

Say I have a program that asks the user his/her age? When I execute it in KDevelop I can see the output (the question) but I can't add any input.

when I run the program in Ubuntu's terminal, it works fine, but I can't input anything in KDevelop.

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, KDevelop 4.3.1, KDE 4.8.4.

Answer (score 8):

You can't. Activate the "Use External Terminal" option in the launch configuration.

If you want to debug this is not supported - in that case you have to run your application manually in a terminal and attach the debugger.

Comment: There is no "Use External Terminal" option in Kdevelop v4.7.0.